# Database timestamp mismatch

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, timezone

In our database there is a table called order, that table has a column called created_at which is a timestamp column.
when a customer creates an order we set that field by current timestamp.
so the problem is when we dump our SQL file by mysqldump (directly from the server) the sql file show that, the number one order created at - 2017-01-01 10:27:35, which is **exactly correct**.

SQL DUMPED QUERY :

```
INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES (1,'2017-01-01 10:27:35'');
```

But when we open that order from our web application it shows that the order created at - 04:27 PM, Jan 01 2017 (+6 Hour ahead, which is wrong).

[image]

Also when we create a MySQL query it also shows that the order created at - 04:27 PM, Jan 01 2017 (+6 Hour ahead, which is wrong).

[image]

This problem occurs 24-04-2018, on that day's ubuntu update our MySQL server from 5.7.21 to 5.7.22. On MySQL error log, there is a mismatch +6 hours.

[image]

> at line 44 - Buffer pool(s). dump completed at 180424 21:34:16(log
>   entry at 15:34:16 but in details log is shows dump completed at 180424
>   21:34:16 where is 6 hours delay).

---

> Currently, when we create an order, the created_at fields show
>   perfectly on web application and mysql query, but when we dump sql
>   data, it shows **created at 6 hours delay**.

## Note:

1. our application time zone set UTC + 6, Asia/Dhaka
2. Mysql Version: Server version    5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
3. SQL Dumped againest - /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
4. problematic field - all timestamp column
5. our system time set as UTC + 6 and mysql global & session time set as system.
6. systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service

Output:

```
$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d
           └─disable-with-time-daemon.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-02-06 16:53:59 +06; 2 months 18 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
 Main PID: 11383 (systemd-timesyn)
   Status: "Synchronized to time server 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com)."
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 564.0K
      CPU: 4.272s
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
           └─11383 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
```

Comment: Pls do not ask multiple questions in a single post.

Comment: @Shadow sorry for that, but those 2 issue are same and related with each other.

Comment: Isn't `10:27:35 +0600` exactly the same moment as `04:27 PM UTC`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes, exactly same, but before 24 April, our web application shows 10:27 AM

Answer (score 2):

From [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html) (emphasis mine):

> The current session time zone setting affects display and storage of time values that are zone-sensitive. This includes the values displayed by functions such as `NOW()` or `CURTIME()`, and values stored in and retrieved from `TIMESTAMP` columns. **Values for `TIMESTAMP` columns are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.**

Since you said your MySQL global and session time zone variables are set for `SYSTEM`, and the system time zone is `Asia/Dhaka` (UTC+6), then it appears everything is working as designed.

Note that per the [mysqldump docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tz-utc) for the `--tz-utc` option:

> ... mysqldump sets its connection time zone to UTC and adds `SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00'` to the dump file. ... `--tz-utc` is enabled by default.  To disable it, use `--skip-tz-utc`.

Since you said the output from the dump file has the correct time, then unless you're passing the `--skip-tz-utc` flag, your data was inserted in terms of UTC  (i.e., with the session time zone set to `+00:00` during insert).

Then, since your application is seeing the times shifted 6 hours ahead, your application is probably not setting the session time zone, and thus `SYSTEM` prevails.

There are two options:

- Call `SET TIME_ZONE='SYSTEM'` before your insert statement (or figure out where you're setting `+00:00` and stop doing that)  This will make the items in the database based on the system time zone.
- Call `SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00'` in your application, such that you query the values out in UTC rather than 6 hours ahead.  This makes the items in the database UTC based (which is preferred).